# How to pass values as parameters in sql query in geoserver view

Tags: postgresql, postgis, geoserver

I am trying to write sql view in geoserver and pass lat long as parameters to get the result. The query is working fine in Postgres. Now I am writing query in geoserver.

Working query is:

```
select gid ,
  objectid ,
  locality,
  location,
  longitude,
  latitude ,x ,y,geom 
from tablename 
ORDER BY ST_SetSRID(ST_Point('75', '15'), 4326) <-> geom  
LIMIT 10
```

I am trying to pass it as a parameters like

```
select gid ,
  objectid ,
  abl_record ,
  district_n ,
  locality_n,
  location_i,
  longitude,
  latitude ,
  x ,
  y,geom  
  from tablename 
  where x=%x% 
    and y=%y% 
  ORDER BY ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(x, y), 4326) <-> geom  
  LIMIT 10
```

Comment: But what is not working exactly? The query syntax in Geoserver looks fine

Comment: Thanks It is working fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working fine for me. We have to create view query like

```
select * 
from tablename 
ORDER BY ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(%longitude% , %latitude%), 4326) <-> geom 
LIMIT 10
```